# react native IAP : Subscription always return status: 21002 a

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, in-app-purchase

I am working on auth renewable subscription. But every time i goes for the reciept validation it gives me  error **21002**

```
      const validateIOSReceipt = async (receipt) => {
    const isTestEnvironment = __DEV__;

    const receiptBody = {
      'receipt-data': receipt,
      password: DataConfig.IAP_SHARED_SECRET
    };
    console.log('receiptBody data',receiptBody)
    try {
      const validatedReceipt = await validateReceiptIos(
        receiptBody,
        isTestEnvironment,
      );
        console.log('receiptBody responce',validatedReceipt)
      return validatedReceipt;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      return {};
    }
  };



{receipt-data: "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", 'password': "a56a9*****9b4bf5d1a6ddc9591a2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your receipt data does not arrive correctly at Apple's end:

> 21002
> The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or the service experienced a temporary issue. Try again.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status) for all codes

Comment: I am trying since 24 hours.. What should i do

Comment: It is hard to tell based on your current code snipped. What does `validateReceiptIos` do?

Comment: First of all, I would assure that the receipt data is correct by using one of the endless API testing tools or cURL to send the receipt data. If the receipt data is correct, I would reverse engineer where my code doesn't do what it should.

Comment: validateReceiptIos is the react-native-iap method

Comment: Corresponding to this issue https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/1127 the react-native implementation doesn't work with debug builds. It seems to work only with TestFlight or production builds

Comment: @PaulSchröder Where is this mentioned?

Comment: @red-devil that it doesn't work with debug builds?